# how to apply strptime(string,format) on StringProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, strptime

[solved]
i mixed up class method and instance method before. so when i

tried to call strptime(cls.ts,format) inside @classmethod function , i was actually calling

ts = ndb.StringProperty() or StringProperty('ts'),but
not the string value inside ts.

the correct one is to remove @ decorator and call

strptime(self.ts,format) .

**original question below**

1:when the Token instance is created , init_created() is called to inititalize ts to a string.

2:user request the verification handler , with token as a arg , the token is used to retrieve 
  the Token instance.

3:i use the Token instance to call is_valid() .In is_valid , i convert ts back to datetime obj,
  to compare to other datetime obj.

error 1 :

when i set( with the str() method )

```
delta = (now-datetime.strptime(str(cls.ts),'%Y-%b-%d / %H:%M:%S:%f')).total_seconds()
```

i get

```
ValueError: time data "StringProperty('ts')" does not match format '%Y-%b-%d / %H:%M:%S:%f'
```

error 2 :
so i try another way. i set (without str() )

```
delta = (now-datetime.strptime(cls.ts,'%Y-%b-%d / %H:%M:%S:%f')).total_seconds()
```

i get

```
TypeError: must be string, not StringProperty
```

so my question is how to correctly pass a stringproperty to strptime method.

thank you very much .

below is my code:

```
class Token(ndb.Model):
     ts = ndb.StringProperty()

     @classmethod
     def init_created(cls):
          ts = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=8)).strftime(format='%Y-%b-%d / %H:%M:%S:%f')
          return ts
     @classmethod
     def is_valid(cls):
          now = (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=8))
          delta = (now-datetime.strptime(cls.ts,'%Y-%b-%d / %H:%M:%S:%f')).total_seconds()
          return (delta<expire_time)


class Verification(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self , token ):
         token_cls = Token.query(Token.token == token ).get()
         if not (token_cls and token_cls.is_valid() ) :
              template = jinja_environment.get_template('verification_error.html' )
              pass


    must be string, not StringProperty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s/1.374948928179626607/main.py", line 216, in get
    if not (token_cls and token_cls.is_valid() ) :
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~/1.374948928179626607/main.py", line 86, in is_valid
    delta = (now-datetime.strptime(cls.ts,'%Y-%b-%d / %H:%M:%S:%f')).total_seconds()
TypeError: must be string, not StringProperty
```

Comment: You're accessing the property of a Model class, rather than a Model instance. Show more code if this isn't enough for you to figure out your mistake.

Comment: sorry for lack of info before. i've add more code now ,thanks for reminder.                                                             i first get the model instance with Token.query , then i use the instance(token_cls) to call is_valid() . is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `is_valid` method shouldn't have the `@classmethod` decorator, as with it you're operating on the `Token` class, and not on the entity returned from your query. Once you've removed the decorator, it would be idiomatic to change `cls` to `self`.

Comment: i see... i mixed up cls and instance method before. thank you !